# MAGMA question concerning the ordering of Irr($G\times H$)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, magma-cas

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups.

Denote the ordinary character table of $G$ by ctG and the ordinary character table of $H$ by ctH.

Then, it is well-known how to get the ordinary character table of $G\times H$.

> Is it possible to get the ordinary character table of $G\times H$ in MAGMA in such a way that the ordering of the ordinary irreducible characters is
>
> $\chi_1 \times \psi_1,\ \chi_2 \times \psi_1,\ \chi_3 \times \psi_1,\ \chi_4 \times \psi_1,\ \dots ,\ \chi_2 \times \psi_1,\ \chi_2 \times \psi_2,\ \chi_2 \times \psi_3,\ \dots$ (where the $\chi_i$ are the ordinary characters in ctG and the $\psi_j$ are those in ctH)?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

I mean an easier way than computing $G\times H$, restricting each ordinary irred. char. of Irr($G\times H$) to $G$ and $H$, respectively, and then changing the ordering.

Comment: Why not just compute the character tables of $G$ and $H$ and use the results to compute that of $G \times H$? I expect it would only be a few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. How can one construct one's own character table in MAGMA?